# Use an element to make a "window" in the one behind it

Tags: html, css, transparency

I'm trying to achieve an effect with HTML and CSS wherein I can define a region that becomes sort of like a window in an element. I can't just put a white div in front, because I would like the window to reveal what is behind the element, like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA0a8.png) example, where a hole is cut in the orange element to reveal what is behind. Is this at all possible using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS border to do so:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.mask {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 50px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 200px auto;
  border-left-width: 200px;
  border-top-width: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
  abc
</div>
```

It's like a mask, but the content is still visible as well as the background.